# Организация игровой логики

Tags: c#, winforms, разработка-игр

Разрабатываю свою игру в жанре scroll shooter с помощью WinForms на шарпе. В игре есть множество различных объектов, которые выделены в классы и тд.
Каждый тик таймера форму вызывается метод Update(), который должен передвигать все объекты на поле. Проблема заключается в том, что я не знаю, как правильно организовать проверку пересечений всех объектов. В данный момент есть две мысли. Первая - организовать всю логику в самом методе Update. Вторая - организовать проверку пересечений с другими объектами в самих классах. 
Возможно у кого-то есть опыт игровой разработки и он сможет мне подсказать наиболее правильный и оптимальный вариант решения данной проблемы[image: Схема пересечений различных объектов]

Comment: Если бы я писал подобную игру, я вы отделил код самой логики игры от кода WinForms, чтобы вся логика просчитывалась отдельно от всего, чтобы можно было бы однажды просто поменять шкурку с WinForms на WPF или Xamarin без изменений в логике самой игры.

Comment: Это уже сделано, есть отдельный класс Game. Вопрос скорее в том, кому лучше обрабатывать эти события классу Game или каждому отдельному классу

Comment: тогда в чем вопрос?

Comment: Я бы  создал бы 2 класса: `PositionsService` - класс вычисляющий наличие и позиции игровых объектов и `CollisionsService` - класс вычисляющий столкновения/пересечения игр. объектов. В методе `Update` я бы вызывал `_positionsService.NextStep()`, а в нем бы вызывал `_collisionsService.GetCollisionObjects()`, как-то так.

Comment: Присоединяюсь к мысли о том, что логику держать в отдельном проекте. Статья по теме: https://habr.com/en/post/322258/

Answer (score 2):

Классическая наивная наипростейшая реализация следующая:

0) При инициализации движка инициализируются компоненты: рендер, обработчик коллизии, обработчик AI...

1) Когда из main loop вызывается Update состояния игры для сцены, каждый компнент вызывается последовательно и обрабатывает сцену

Примечание: для простых движков последовательный вызов вполне укладывается в 60 FPS

2) последовательность вызовов определяете сами. Представляйте это как фазы в настольной игре. Обычно рендер последний, AI после перемещения.

3) простейший обработчик коллизии декларирует несколько слоев для коллизии, которые имеют смысл для обслуживаемого движком gamecore ( статические mesh, неигровые actors, игровые actors), которые могут иметь свою иерархию.

Примечание: слои коллизии относятся к типам объектов на сцене, как рисуемых, так и не отображаемых (границы "игровой" зоны). Даже для игры вид сверху имеет смысл вводить концепцию глубины сцены, явно выраженную дискретную z ось. Тогда просто для вида коллизии полезно добавить сквозной слой коллизии, который бы обрабатывал такие препятствия, которые существуют на всех z уровнях сцены.